# Manipulating time strings to millisecond precision

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror, milliseconds

I found few solutions here to my problem, all of them up-voted a lot, but when i try them, the program crashes.

So, I want to convert a string to a datetime object, and then to add or subtract time to it.
All of the strings share the same structure --> 00:00:40,249 (example) which marks 00 hours, 00 minutes, 40 seconds and 249 milliseconds.
When i convert it to datetime object, i get this :

00:00:40.249000 (extra 3 zeros marking microseconds).

I must remove these 3 zeros to get the time in the same format.

All of the solutions I found to this were pretty straight-forward. My code today:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(line.partition(saparator)[0], '%H:%M:%S,%f').time()
```

The solutions I found:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(line.partition(saparator)[0], '%H:%M:%S,%f').time()[:-3]
```

When i do so i get the following:

TypeError: 'datetime.time' object is not subscriptable

Once again, these solutions were upvoted and got many thanks from users, how come mine doesnt work?

Thank you all!

Comment: the `datetime.time` object does not use milliseconds as it doesn't exist, the only attribute available is the microseconds which has the three extra zeroes

Comment: This is a an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should show us your code, and what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to slice a datetime object instead of a string.

```
TypeError: 'datetime.time'
```

You need to cast the variable as a String, then you can slice it.

As per the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects):

```
time.isoformat()
```

This will return the time as a string.

Answer (score 0):

A string like that looks more like an elapsed time or a time interval, at least to me. That being the case, I would suggest using a `timedelta` object to represent it. One advantage of doing this is that it's easy to add and subtract arbitrary intervals of time from it.

First the conversion: I've chosen to split items from your string using a regex but of course you could use any technique you find most convenient. I begin by creating a dictionary for all of the parameters to the `timedelta` creation function, in `timedelta_args`. Then I replace selected items in this dictionary with the values I parse from your string using the regex. Then I pass all of the values in the dictionary to `timedelta`, taking care to put the values in the order expected by this function. The value of `timespan` is what I had hoped for, as are values of its properties.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> import re
>>> s = '00:00:40,249'
>>> timedelta_args = {'days':0, 'seconds':0, 'microseconds':0, 'milliseconds':0, 'minutes':0, 'hours':0, 'weeks':0}
>>> timedelta_args['hours'], timedelta_args['minutes'], timedelta_args['seconds'], timedelta_args['milliseconds'] = map(int, re.split(r'[:,]', s))
>>> timespan = timedelta(*[timedelta_args[_] for _ in ['days', 'seconds', 'microseconds', 'milliseconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'weeks']])
>>> timespan
datetime.timedelta(0, 40, 249000)
>>> timespan.seconds
40
>>> timespan.microseconds
249000
```

I can obtain a string representation of `timespan` easily, and as long as the number of milliseconds is 1,000 or more I can easily obtain the original string.

```
>>> str(timespan)
'0:00:40.249000'
>>> str(timespan)[:-3]
'0:00:40.249'
>>> str(timespan)[:-3].replace('.', ',')
'0:00:40,249'
```

Since `timespan` is a `timedelta` I can add to it (and subtract from it). The raw result may not look very satisfactory; however, the `str` function soon makes up for this.

```
>>> timespan + timedelta(hours=3, seconds=20)
datetime.timedelta(0, 10860, 249000)
>>> str(timespan + timedelta(hours=3, seconds=20))
'3:01:00.249000'
```

When you're formatting though beware of one fairly minor hitch. When the `microseconds` property is zero it's left off entirely in the string representation.

```
>>> str(timespan + timedelta(hours=3, microseconds=751000))
'3:00:41'
```